# Loading macros from .XLS file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an .XLS file with macros I have to modify and keep the macros and images it contains. I can open the file and modify the cell data but it loses the macros and images. I tried to search for the problem on Google but I only found solutions for .xlsm files. I hope it's possible to keep the macros in an .xls file too. Here is my code for the opening and saving:

```
include_once libraries_get_path('PHPExcel').'/PHPExcel.php';
include_once libraries_get_path('PHPExcel').'/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$template = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('private://xls/form_template.xls');
$template->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Modifying the cells data here...
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($template, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('sites/default/files/'.$filename);
```

It's a really important function in the project and the customer needs it ASAP.

Comment: PHPExcel does not support macros

Comment: Thanks. I hoped that the problem has been solved, I saw some answers from 2012 which says it does not support macros but I hoped this issue has been solved since than.

Comment: @MarkBaker what was https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/252 for then?

Comment: @Gordon - Only applies to OfficeOpenXML-format (xlsx) files, not BIFF-format (xls) files